# Install data directory tree with massive number of files using automake

Tags: installation, autotools, autoconf, automake

I have a data directory which I would like automake to generate install and uninstall targets for.  Essentially, I just want to copy this directory verbatim to the DATA directory,  Normally, I might list all the files individually, like

```
dist_whatever_DATA=dir/subdir/filea ...
```

But the problem arises when my directory structure looks like this

```
*root
 *subdir
  *~10 files
 *subdir
  *~10 files
 *subdir
  *~700 files
 *subdir
 ...
 ~20 subdirs
```

I just *cannot* list all 1000+ files included as part of my Makefile.am. That would be ridiculous.

I need to preserve the directory structure as well.  I should note that this data is *not* generated at all by the build process, and is actually largely short audio recordings.  So it's not like I would want automake to "check" that every file I want to install has actually been created, as they're either there or not, and whatever file is there, I know I want it to be installed, and whatever file is not, should not be installed.  I know that this is the justification used in other places to not do wildcard instsalls, but all the possible reasons don't apply here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found that installing hundreds of files separately makes for a tormentingly long invocation of `make install`. I had a similar case where I wanted to install hundreds of files, preserving the directory structure, and I did not want to change my Makefile.am every time a file was added to or removed from the collection.

I included a LZMA archive of the files in my distribution, and made automake rules like so:

```
GIANTARCHIVE = My_big_archive.tar.lz

dist_pkgdata_DATA = $(GIANTARCHIVE)

install-data-hook:
    cd $(DESTDIR)$(pkgdatadir); \
    cat $(GIANTARCHIVE) | unlzma | $(TAR) --list > uninstall_manifest.txt; \
    cat $(GIANTARCHIVE) | unlzma | $(TAR) --no-same-owner --extract; \
    rm --force $(GIANTARCHIVE); \
    cat uninstall_manifest.txt | sed --expression='s/^\|$$/"/g' | xargs chmod a=rX,u+w

uninstall-local:
    cd $(DESTDIR)$(pkgdatadir); \
    cat uninstall_manifest.txt | sed --expression='s/ /\\ /g' | xargs rm --force; \
    rm --force uninstall_manifest.txt
```

This way, automake installs `My_big_archive.tar.lz` in the `$(pkgdata)` directory, and extracts it there, making a list of all the files that were in it, so it can uninstall them later. This also runs much faster than listing each file as an install target, even if you were to autogenerate that list.

Comment: Why do you install this into `$(pkgdatadir)`? Just extract it from `$(srcdir)` in `install-data-hook`. Use something like `EXTRA_DIST = giant_archive.tar.lzma` so it is distributed.

Comment: Three minor suggestions, unrelated to the actual question.  I would replace `cat xxx | yyy | zzz` by `yyyy <xxx | zzz` to simplify the work of the OS (it can also be written `<xxx yyy | zzz` if you want to keep `xxx` at the beginning of the line).  Also you can probably extract in verbose mode in order to create your manifest at the same time (avoiding the two decompressions of the big archive).  Finally the use of all those long options (e.g. `rm --force` instead of `rm -f`) makes your `Makefile` non-portable outside of the GNU world, while it could easily be.

Comment: @adl, thanks! I always thought that using long options in scripts made the scripts easier to read, but portability is better.

Answer (score 11):

I would use a script to generate a `Makefile` fragment that lists all the files:

```
echo 'subdir_files =' > subfiles.mk
find subdir -type f -print | sed 's/^/  /;$q;s/$/ \\/' >> subfiles.mk
```

and then include this `subfiles.mk` from your main `Makefile.am`:

```
include $(srcdir)/subfiles.mk
nobase_dist_pkgdata_DATA = $(subdir_files)
```

---

A second option is to `EXTRA_DIST = subdir`, and then to write custom `install-data-local` and `uninstall-local` rules.

The problem here is that `EXTRA_DIST = subdir` will distributes all files in `subdir/`, including backup files, configuration files (e.g. from your VCS), and other things you would not want to distribute.

Using a script as above let you filter the files you really want to distribute.

Comment: Just a note: The first one doesn't work, as it fails with "make[2]: execvp: /bin/bash: Argument list too long"

Comment: Wow!  I am generating some `Makefile`s with pretty large lists of files, but had not *yet* realized I would hit the command line size limit some day!

Comment: Could you give an example of the second option? If I just "cp -Rf" I get wrong permissions and I need to chmod after cp (or maybe umask before cp). I looked into automatically generated rules, they use $(INSTALL_DATA) instead of cp, but in this case all files need to be specified, so this would require "find", etc. What's the best, most portable way to install whole directory in install-data-local?

Comment: @marcin Something like this http://www.google.com/codesearch#EIS5BlthS9Y/Makefile.am&q=install-data-local%20INSTALL_DATA&type=cs

Comment: The find command has a printf output option which might be easier to understand then piping to sed.

Comment: @Ishmael: the GNU implementation of `find` has a `-printf` option, but it this is not a standard option.  If you want your Makefiles to be portable, you should avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

I would write a script (either as a separate shell script, or in the `Makefile.am`), that is run as part of the [`install-data-hook`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/automake/Extending.html) target.